# How to find the height of a binary tree in C without using recursion?

Tags: tree, iteration, binary-tree

Can I get the logic of the maximum depth of the binary tree in C language without using recursion .

Answer (score 0):

To get the height of a tree without using Recursion is to do BFS (which is non recursive) over the tree. And keep track of the level you are reaching. The last level's number should be your depth of the tree.

The pseudo code of above approach should be like that:

```
Q: Queue like data structure
root: root of your tree
couter = 0 // variable which will denote depth.
1. Q -> add ( root)
2. while ( Q is not empty) 
2.1 size = Q-> size ();
  2.2 while( size -- > 0)
  2.2.1 Process your tree
  2.2.2 Increment: Counter 
  End of While (2.2)
End of While (2)
```